# Laravel model is returning null for belongsTo and hasOne. PhpMyAdmin says "Link not found!", but the key exists and is directly accessible in both

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have two models named: Subject and Group, Subject has a group_id column with a foreign key setup to point to the groups' table.

When I call $subject->group it returns null; it should return the Group model that the Subject belongs to. I can manually get the Group by calling Group::where('id', '=', $subject->group_id) and *that* works fine. The $subject variable is also working as expected.

What I've tried in the Subject model:

```php
// Not all at once obviously, it's just easier to show what I've tried like this.
public function group(): BelongsTo {
     return $this->hasOne(Group::class, 'id', 'group_id');
     return $this->belongsTo(Group::class, 'id', 'group_id');
     return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}
```

web.php:

```php
Route::get('/subjects/{subject}', [App\Http\Controllers\SubjectsController::class, 'subject'])->name('subject');
```

How I'm testing in my controller:

```
public function subject(Request $request, Subject $subject) 
{
    dd($subject->group);
}
```

dd($subject) returns a subject model object filled with expected data. Returning $subject->group() returns a group model object but no data in it.

What I've tried so far:

```php
// php artisan tinker:
$s = Subject::first(); $g = Group::where('id', $s->group_id)->firstOrFail();
```

Returns

```
  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException  No query results for model [App\Models\Group].
```

```php
        $testSub = Subject::where('id', '=', 4074)->first();
        $testGroup = Group::where('id', '=', $testSub['group_id'])->first();
dd($testSub, $testGroup, $testSub->group);
```

Returns the subject and group model objects filled with the expected data. $testSub->group returns null.

I called

```php
dd($student->is($testSub));
```

And it returns true

Something that *does* work is:

```php
$subject->group()->get()
```

But that isn't ideal.

Using 'with' either in the model as a protected member or calling the method, does not work.

Comment: Third one should be used (from explained logic) `return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);`. What do you get if you `dd($subject->group());`? It should return relation object.

Comment: Haven't used phpMyAdmin in awhile, but doesn't it just "link" when the foreign keys have been properly defined? In any case, can you edit your question to show **how** you are accessing the `subject` action? What is the route you defined for it? Can you also try this in `php artisan tinker`: `$s = Subject::first(); $g = Group::where('id', $s->group_id)->firstOrFail();` ? Are both the `groups` and `subjects` table in the same database? If they are, and their fields are as you say, then it *should* be `belongsTo(Group::class)`.

Comment: $subject->group() returns a BelongsTo relation object. $s = Subject::first(); $g = Group::where('id', $s->group_id)->firstOrFail(); returns "No query results for model [App\Models\Group]". Groups and subjects are both in the same database. I'll update my post, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had another column named 'group' in the subjects table that was interfering. Changed the name of the method and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the input parameter "$subject" has right data.

I use the following relationship in the subject model can get the group data.

```
public function group(): BelongsTo {
     return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this and it doesn't work. I updated my question with more info but the summary is that the data in $subject is as expected, and manually getting the group using Group::where() works as expected as well.